# How to print time in hh:mm format for following code

Tags: batch-file

Following code displays the time value in only h:mm format , I want the output to be in  hh:mm. Could any one please identify where to add what.
Below is my input file.
I have also added putput at the bottom.

---

```
@ECHO OFF 
ECHO Task calculation


set /P st=Please enter the CRQ Start time(hh:mm)


set calc1=00:30
set calc2=01:00 
set calc3=01:00
set calc4=00:30


set task1=st



set /A centis=(1%st:~0,2%-100)*3600+(1%st:~3,2%-100)*60
if %centis% GTR 86400 set centis=0
set /A c1=(%calc1:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc1:~3,2%)*60
set /A c2=(%calc2:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc2:~3,2%)*60
set /A c3=(%calc3:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc3:~3,2%)*60
set /A c4=(%calc4:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc4:~3,2%)*60


set /a t1=centis+c1
if %t1% GTR 86400 set t1=0
set /a t1h=t1/3600
set /a t1m=(t1-(t1h*3600))/60


set /a t2=t1+c2
if %t2% GTR 86400 set t2=0
set /a t2h=t2/3600
set /a t2m=(t2-(t2h*3600))/60


set /a t3=t2+c3
if %t3% GTR 86400 set t3=0
set /a t3h=t3/3600
set /a t3m=(t3-(t3h*3600))/60


set /a t4=t3+c4
if %t4% GTR 86400 set t4=0
set /a t4h=t4/3600
set /a t4m=(t4-(t4h*3600))/60



echo.
echo TASK1 StartTime :%st%
echo.
echo Task1 EndTime :%t1h%:%t1m%
echo.


echo Task2 StartTime :%t1h%:%t1m%
echo.
echo Task2 EndTime :%t2h%:%t2m%
echo.


echo Task3 StartTime :%t2h%:%t2m%
echo.
echo Task3 EndTime :%t3h%:%t3m%
echo.


echo Task4 StartTime :%t3h%:%t3m%
echo.
echo Task4 EndTime :%t4h%:%t4m%
echo.


echo CRQ EndTime :%t4h%:%t4m%
echo.


pause>null
```

---

Output below :

```
Task calculation
Please enter the CRQ Start time(hh:mm)07:00

TASK1 StartTime :07:00

Task1 EndTime :7:30

Task2 StartTime :7:30

Task2 EndTime :8:30

Task3 StartTime :8:30

Task3 EndTime :9:30

Task4 StartTime :9:30

Task4 EndTime :10:0

CRQ EndTime :10:0
```

Comment: `if %tXh% lss 10 set tXh=0%tXh%` for all times.

Answer (score 0):

[npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) has answered already this question.

Here is nevertheless an answer for this question with complete batch code containing a block to insert a leading 0 for all hours and minutes output finally output by the batch file. The hour and minute entered by the user is still not evaluated before processing them.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Task calculation

set /P "st=Please enter the CRQ start time [hh:mm]: "

set calc1=00:30
set calc2=01:00
set calc3=01:00
set calc4=00:30

set /A centis=(1%st:~0,2%-100)*3600+(1%st:~3,2%-100)*60
if %centis% GTR 86400 set centis=0
set /A c1=(%calc1:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc1:~3,2%)*60
set /A c2=(%calc2:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc2:~3,2%)*60
set /A c3=(%calc3:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc3:~3,2%)*60
set /A c4=(%calc4:~0,2%)*3600+(%calc4:~3,2%)*60

set /a t1=centis+c1
if %t1% GTR 86400 set t1=0
set /a t1h=t1/3600
set /a t1m=(t1-(t1h*3600))/60

set /a t2=t1+c2
if %t2% GTR 86400 set t2=0
set /a t2h=t2/3600
set /a t2m=(t2-(t2h*3600))/60

set /a t3=t2+c3
if %t3% GTR 86400 set t3=0
set /a t3h=t3/3600
set /a t3m=(t3-(t3h*3600))/60

set /a t4=t3+c4
if %t4% GTR 86400 set t4=0
set /a t4h=t4/3600
set /a t4m=(t4-(t4h*3600))/60

if %t1h% lss 10 set t1h=0%t1h%
if %t2h% lss 10 set t2h=0%t2h%
if %t3h% lss 10 set t3h=0%t3h%
if %t4h% lss 10 set t4h=0%t4h%
if %t1m% lss 10 set t1m=0%t1m%
if %t2m% lss 10 set t2m=0%t2m%
if %t3m% lss 10 set t3m=0%t3m%
if %t4m% lss 10 set t4m=0%t4m%

echo.
echo Task1 StartTime: %st%
echo.
echo Task1 EndTime:   %t1h%:%t1m%
echo.

echo Task2 StartTime: %t1h%:%t1m%
echo.
echo Task2 EndTime:   %t2h%:%t2m%
echo.

echo Task3 StartTime: %t2h%:%t2m%
echo.
echo Task3 EndTime:   %t3h%:%t3m%
echo.

echo Task4 StartTime: %t3h%:%t3m%
echo.
echo Task4 EndTime:   %t4h%:%t4m%
echo.

echo CRQ EndTime:     %t4h%:%t4m%
echo.

pause >nul
```